# better approach to get the value of radio button other than click event

Tags: angularjs

i am trying to get the value of the radio button. So i have written a click event and in the click i am passing the value. So that whenever the user clicks on any of the radio button only the latest clicked radio buttons value is set. Is there any better approach to this? Like checking which radio button is checked and display the corresponding value.

**JS**

```
;(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('tramsConsole',[])
        .controller('TremorController', TremorController);

    TremorController.$inject = ['$scope', '$log'];

    function TremorController($scope, $log) {
        var vm = this;
        vm.status='';
        vm.datametric = "";
        console.log("controller loaded");
        vm.getstatus = getstatus;

        function getstatus(obj){
            vm.status = obj;
        }

    }        
})();
```

**HTML**

```
<body ng-app="tramsConsole">
    <div ng-controller="TremorController as tremorController">
            <input type="radio" name="data" value="NUM_ERRORS" ng-model="processState.widgetInstance.configuration.data.NUM_ERRORS" ng-click="tremorController.getstatus('NUM_ERRORS')">NUM_ERRORS<br>
            <input type="radio" name="data" value="NUM_UB_OCCURRENCES" ng-model="processState.widgetInstance.configuration.data.NUM_UB_OCCURRENCES" ng-click="tremorController.getstatus('NUM_UB_OCCURRENCES')">NUM_UB_OCCURRENCES<br>
            <input type="radio" name="data" value="NUM_T_OCCURRENCES" ng-model="processState.widgetInstance.configuration.data.NUM_T_OCCURRENCES" ng-click="tremorController.getstatus('NUM_T_OCCURRENCES')">NUM_T_OCCURRENCES<br>
            <input type="radio" name="data" value="NUM_OCCURRENCES" ng-model="processState.widgetInstance.configuration.data.NUM_OCCURRENCES" ng-click="tremorController.getstatus('NUM_OCCURRENCES')">NUM_OCCURRENCES<br>
            <input type="radio" name="data" value="AVG_RSP_TIME" ng-model="processState.widgetInstance.configuration.data.AVG_RSP_TIME" ng-click="tremorController.getstatus('AVG_RSP_TIME')">AVG_RSP_TIME<br>
            <input type="radio" name="data" value="UB_AVG_RSP_TIME" ng-model="processState.widgetInstance.configuration.data.UB_AVG_RSP_TIME" ng-click="tremorController.getstatus('UB_AVG_RSP_TIME')">UB_AVG_RSP_TIME<br>
            <input type="radio" name="data" value="T_AVG_RSP_TIME" ng-model="processState.widgetInstance.configuration.data.T_AVG_RSP_TIME" ng-click="tremorController.getstatus('T_AVG_RSP_TIME')">T_AVG_RSP_TIME<br>
            <input type="radio" name="data" value="UB_SQR_AVG_RSP_TIME" ng-model="processState.widgetInstance.configuration.data.UB_SQR_AVG_RSP_TIME" ng-click="tremorController.getstatus('UB_SQR_AVG_RSP_TIME')">UB_SQR_AVG_RSP_TIME<br>
            <input type="radio" name="data" value="T_SQR_AVG_RSP_TIME" ng-model="processState.widgetInstance.configuration.data.T_SQR_AVG_RSP_TIME" ng-click="tremorController.getstatus('T_SQR_AVG_RSP_TIME')">T_SQR_AVG_RSP_TIME<br>
            <input type="radio" name="data" value="SQR_AVG_RSP_TIME" ng-model="processState.widgetInstance.configuration.data.SQR_AVG_RSP_TIME" ng-click="tremorController.getstatus('SQR_AVG_RSP_TIME')">SQR_AVG_RSP_TIME<br>


  <br>
  <div>

    The selected Value is :

    {{tremorController.status}}


  </div>
   </div>
  </body>
```

[Working Copy](http://plnkr.co/edit/U9WubU4UpUrlru8zBYvA?p=preview)

Comment: angularjs has an directive called **radio**, you only need one ng-model:[here is the doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bradio%5D)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've edited your plunker here: http://plnkr.co/edit/VAAqiW3jMmAwAROJTg0G?p=preview

If you set the ng-model to be the same, the value of the selected button will be reflected in that model:

**HTML**

```
   <div ng-controller="TremorController as tremorController">
            <input type="radio" name="data" value="NUM_ERRORS" ng-model="radioButtons">NUM_ERRORS<br>
            <input type="radio" name="data" value="NUM_UB_OCCURRENCES" ng-model="radioButtons">NUM_UB_OCCURRENCES<br>
            <input type="radio" name="data" value="NUM_T_OCCURRENCES" ng-model="radioButtons">NUM_T_OCCURRENCES<br>
            <input type="radio" name="data" value="NUM_OCCURRENCES" ng-model="radioButtons">NUM_OCCURRENCES<br>
            <input type="radio" name="data" value="AVG_RSP_TIME" ng-model="radioButtons">AVG_RSP_TIME<br>
            <input type="radio" name="data" value="UB_AVG_RSP_TIME" ng-model="radioButtons">UB_AVG_RSP_TIME<br>
            <input type="radio" name="data" value="T_AVG_RSP_TIME" ng-model="radioButtons">T_AVG_RSP_TIME<br>
            <input type="radio" name="data" value="UB_SQR_AVG_RSP_TIME" ng-model="radioButtons">UB_SQR_AVG_RSP_TIME<br>
            <input type="radio" name="data" value="T_SQR_AVG_RSP_TIME" ng-model="radioButtons">T_SQR_AVG_RSP_TIME<br>
            <input type="radio" name="data" value="SQR_AVG_RSP_TIME" ng-model="radioButtons">SQR_AVG_RSP_TIME<br>


  <br>
  <div>

    The selected Value is : {{radioButtons}}

  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can write a custom directive for getting the value of radio button in controller.

```
    app.directive('buttonId', function () {
       return {
           restrict: "A",
           link: function (scope, element, attributes) {
               element.bind("click", function () {
                   scope.selectedRadioButton = attributes.buttonId;                
               });
           }
       }
    });
```

to use the directive in html you can

```
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="female" button-id="3" > Female<br>
```